# Return type of inherited static function

Tags: c++, inheritance, matrix, static, static-polymorphism

happy new year!
I'm relatively new to both C++ and its community, so sorry for any mistake.

I'm implementing a `mat` (matrix) class with `mat static Zeros(const int rows, const int cols)` function, with `mat` return type. I want to implement a subclass `sqmat` (square matrix) with the same `Zeros` function, but returning `sqmat`.

I've come to this solution:

```
class mat{
private:

    int rows;
    int cols;
    double* data;

public:

    mat(int rows, int cols){
        this -> rows = rows;
        this -> cols = cols;
        data = new double[rows*cols];
    }

    virtual ~mat(){ delete data; }

    static mat Zeros(int rows, int cols){
        mat matrix(rows, cols); 
        matrix.zero();          
        return matrix;
    }

    mat& zero(){
        for(int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
            data[i] = 0;
        return *this;
    }
}

class sqmat : public mat {
public:

    sqmat(int dim) : mat(dim){};

    static sqmat Zeros(int dim){
        sqmat matrix(dim);  
        matrix.zero();          
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

In other words, I've used a backup member function `zero` that makes all the calculations, while I've used the static functions in the parent and child classes to handle the return type. This avoids code repetitions, but it doesn't feel right.

This requires, in fact, to create a backup member function for every static function that I want to implement for both the parent and the child classes, only to return the appropriate data type. Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Unfortunately, both on my textbook and on the internet, polymorphism is explained using `void` returning functions, and so I don't have many examples.

PS avoid templates or "advanced" methods please

Comment: To be fair, having `zero()` as a member function would be useful regardless of whether or not you were aiming for static polymorphism, since it gives you an easy way to clear the matrix if you want to reuse it.

Comment: You can zero-initialise an array in C++ pretty easily, without having to explicitly zero it out, though: `int arr[5]{};` or `int* arr = new int[5]{};` both create an `int[5]` array, where every element is `0`.  [If you want your initialiser to be compatible with C, it should be `{0}` instead of `{}`, if I remember correctly.]  Like [this](http://ideone.com/Pd7hxF).

Comment: You have bigger problems than just initialization. This class [violates the Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419905/return-type-of-inherited-static-function), and, as such, the shown `Zeros()` class member function is guranteed to result in a crash, unless your compiler chooses to elide the implicit copy. Besides figuring out what you're asking about, you will need to implement a proper copy-constructor, and an assignment operator for this class.

Comment: You may look to [Circle-ellipse_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) about your inheritance `sqmat` and `mat`.

Comment: @Jarod42 the page you linked to is a good one. I'll use that in future when beating back the hoards of inappropriate polymorphism monsters.

Comment: I know that having a member zero function would be useful, this is not the point. I know that resetting a vector is easy and doesn't require a static function: this problem applies to ANY static function that I want to inherit and that differ from the parent one only for the different return data type. I know that I need a copy constructor and an assignment operator: it's pretty obvious that I've limited the example to the bare minimum. Please stay on topic.